# Open iphone system map in iphone and ipad with latlong in swift4

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2

I have latitude and longitude.i want to set on button click open system apple default map with set selected latitude and longitude and also should be set in map default.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing the problem?

Comment: What have you tried..i found several posts regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

**At Button action paste the following code**

```
let directionsURL = "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=35.6813023,139.7640529&daddr=35.4657901,139.6201192"
guard let url = URL(string: directionsURL) else {
    return
}
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: @Khavar islam Hello,I set my own latlong after open map but its shows Direction not available

Comment: @MoinShaikh Test in real iPhone Device

Comment: i am currently testing in iPhone ,I got open system map in iphone And its shows both source And destination But got messege there "Direction not available" And also red line not draw between locations.

Comment: Here i send link below.I face same issue like that screenshot.Please shows the screenshot and say me what i can do.

Comment: Now your question is different, because now you want to draw route between source and destination, please use google maps

Answer (score 0):

This code can work for you -

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showMapForMyIphone()
    }

    func showMapForMyIphone() {

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = "Enter your latitude"
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = "Enter your longitude"

        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
        let options = 
        [
            MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
        ]

        //This will enable a placemerk for your map
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "Place Name"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
    }
```

Comment: @MoinShaikh Below of this site you will find the url of apple map. Load any of this according to your need.
Link- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: @ Md Rashed Pervez Its code already work for Japan latlong. But When I set my country (India)latlong that time not work its and got messege location is not available between this location.

Comment: My code is below its open in system map but shows direction is not available Please check and say me what can i do.

Comment: @MoinShaikh i think you are entering the wrong lat & long. try once again with this (latitude: 20.5937, longitude: 78.9629).Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: @MoinShaikh Follow this - https://www.raywenderlich.com/160517/mapkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: let url = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=\(21.1896959252438),\(72.8133394012689)&daddr=\(23.0225),\(72.5714)"
     
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:url)!)

Comment: yes i will check but i dont undesatand my correct latlong why not working in above code but when i enter another country latlong its working fine?

Comment: Did you enter this latlong (latitude: 20.5937, longitude: 78.9629). This should work.
let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 20.5937
let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 78.9629

Comment: let directionsURL = "http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=21.1896959252438,72.8133394012689&daddr=23.0225,72.5714"
        print(directionsURL)
        guard let url = URL(string: directionsURL) else {
            return
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }